# Chat room for quick questions?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Can we have a chat room for questions that we are either too embarrassed or too lazy to post as an actual question.

Questions like "What's the selector for tables that don't have <tables> or <a> children in jQuery" [an answer would be something like `$('table:not(:has(table), :has(a))')` or something similar]

or a question like "What's the algorithm to swap two variables using bitwise operations?" [answer is of course

```
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

]

I find myself needing these dumb ~4 minute google search questions all the time and it would be great if I can ask the communtiy and get an answer and info on the subject if needed.

Maybe there can even be points awarded (like 1 or 2) for the person who answers correctly.

I'm thinking since the amount of people in the room is directly proportionate to the usefulness of such a room, and since most of these questions are pretty basic, there should only be one room for this encompassing all languages.

Comment: There's always IRC if you need quick answers. The Stack Overflow system would be a complete failure in chat if you're thinking of awarding rep and voting etc. Can't see it.

Comment: "chat room for quickies?" - I'm not sure if this is just Australian English, but that just sounds **wrong**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need [100 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) to [create a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new); you have more than enough. You'd need official support to get some sort of rep reward for answered questions in the room, but then you need some way to pose questions and accept answers, which is a good amount of work to design and not really what chat is set up to do -- you might as well just actually post a question on the site, it already has the infrastructure for all this. You can probably get people to help out with trivial problems on chat without a rep bonus involved

Comment: How would I go about getting the prerequisite amount of people (at least 10 active) to join?

Comment: @qwertymk Hope people see it in the room list, I guess

Comment: I would just suggest using the existing chat rooms, like the SO Tavern for general questions or the C# room or Java room or Javascript room ... each of which does exactly what's on the tin all the time for me. Why would creating a room be better than those?

Comment: They could just do something simple where you could "accept" an arbitrary chat message, granting the utterer a couple of points, without a need for it to be associated with a question.  Maybe it could be optionally linked with a previous message to indicate where the question originated.  Then people would be able to pull up that range of messages as a "solution" in response to queries.  Seems like there would be potential for such a system to get out of hand or be intentionally abused, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need a special chat room for this? Just hop into the active JavaScript or HTML rooms on https://chat.stackoverflow.com and ask there. As long as your micro-tiny-question is on topic for the room, *that's what it is there for*.